# vue-cli-service@latest' is not in the npm registry on Windows. Works in WSL

Tags: vue.js, npm

I have a Vue app which I am trying to run using `npm run start`, but this gives me the following error when I run the command from either PowerShell or inside the VS Code terminal:

```
> economyapp@0.1.0 start C:\_code\myapp
> npx vue-cli-service serve

npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/vue-cli-service - Not found
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404  'vue-cli-service@latest' is not in the npm registry.
npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it (or use the name yourself!)
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-11-28T17_22_02_307Z-debug.log
Install for [ 'vue-cli-service@latest' ] failed with code 1
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! economyapp@0.1.0 start: `npx vue-cli-service serve`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the economyapp@0.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-11-28T17_22_02_401Z-debug.log
```

The `npm run start` command works when I run it from inside WSL, however the server does not hot reload when I make changes to the code. I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling Vue CLI and running `npm install`.

Here is my package.json:

```json
{
  "name": "myapp",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "npx vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "npx vue-cli-service build",
    "test": "npx vue-cli-service test:unit",
    "lint": "npx vue-cli-service lint",
    "serve": "npx vue-cli-service serve"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.21.0",
    "core-js": "^3.4.3",
    "lodash": "^4.17.15",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "register-service-worker": "^1.6.2",
    "store2": "^2.11.1",
    "vue": "^3.0.0",
    "vue-router": "^3.1.3",
    "vuex": "^3.1.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/jest": "^24.0.19",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^2.28.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^2.28.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "^4.1.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "^4.1.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-pwa": "^4.1.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-router": "^4.1.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-typescript": "^4.3.1",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-vuex": "^4.1.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "^4.2.3",
    "@vue/devtools": "^5.3.3",
    "@vue/eslint-config-prettier": "^5.0.0",
    "@vue/eslint-config-typescript": "^5.0.2",
    "@vue/test-utils": "1.0.0-beta.29",
    "eslint": "^6.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.1.1",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^6.0.0",
    "lint-staged": "^9.4.3",
    "prettier": "^1.19.1",
    "typescript": "^3.8.3",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.10"
  },
  "gitHooks": {
    "pre-commit": "lint-staged"
  },
  "lint-staged": {
    "*.{js,vue,ts}": [
      "vue-cli-service lint",
      "git add"
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR: Run `npm install`.

`vue-cli-service` is provided by the `@vue/cli-service` in your devDependencies. Because you don't specify the package in the `npx` command, it fails if it has to look in the registry. Without `npx`, your `npm` script will look in `node_modules/.bin` for `vue-cli-service`. You can remove `npx` from your `npm` scripts and you should see the same results you're getting now.

The fact that `npx` isn't finding `vue-cli-service` indicates that you have not run `npm install`. Do that and your `npm` scripts should work as is. Without running `npm install`, you will certainly run into other issues once you fix this one.

If, for some reason, you want the `npm` scripts to work without running `npm install`, you can tell `npx` where to find the binary in the registry. Change `npx vue-cli-service` in your `npm` scripts to be `npx -p @vue/cli-service vue-cli-service` instead and it should fix this problem. But you will certainly run into other problems. You'll want `npm install` regardless.

But to really get at the root of things, you'll need to figure out why the difference between WSL and non-WSL environments in your setup. My guess is that you have `@vue/cli-service` installed globally somewhere that only WSL finds it in your `PATH` but that's just a guess.

Comment: I did run 'npm install' as I said in my original question. The solution was to remove the '^' in front of the version numbers as this was causing npx to download the latest minor version matching the supplied version number, and these minor versions mismatched.